# throw something at/to someone

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition is likely in the following?

> PARIS (AP) — A man seemingly disguised as an old woman in a wheelchair threw a piece of cake at the glass protecting the Mona Lisa at the Louvre Museum and shouted at people to think of planet Earth...

> The man, whose identity was unknown, was also seen throwing roses in the museum gallery **to/at** slack-jawed guests.

https://www.usnews.com/news/entertainment/articles/2022-05-30/man-in-wig-throws-cake-at-glass-protecting-mona-lisa

Answer (score 4):

We throw something **to** an animal or person for them to receive. We throw something **at** a person, animal, or thing as an act of playfulness, aggression or rudeness, or (for a person) when we don't care whether they catch it.

**'At'** is the only preposition which we can use about the cake and the Mona Lisa.

Comment: Here's a photo of the man throwing roses: https://twitter.com/lukeXC2002/status/1530972976501366785?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw

Comment: Somehow "at" is used in the caption. The AP article quoted in the OP, however, uses "to."